# Meteor - get email address of attempted login

Tags: meteor

I need to get the email address that a user was using in a failed login attempt to check if they registered outside of the application.

Here is my code;

```
    Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(info){
    if (!info.allowed)
    {
        console.log("we don't have that user " + info.user.emails[0]['address']);
        return false;
    } else {
        var user = info.user;
        console.log("created " + user.createdAt);
        console.log("emails is " + user.emails[0]['address']);
        return true;
    }
});
```

If the login is not allowed I get this `Cannot read property 'emails' of undefined` because obviously the user is not in the users collection. My question is, is the email and password of the attempted login somehow available to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(info) {                                                                                 
  console.log("user");
  console.dir(info.methodArguments[0].user);
  console.log("password");
  console.dir(info.methodArguments[0].password);
});
```

EDIT: Also, I wrote a Meteor package to solve this problem, available on Atmosphere at https://atmospherejs.com/chipcastledotcom/accounts-email.